# How do I back up my SSD?

Tags: windows, backup

My laptops’ master boot record is messed up, the drive had Windows 10 on it , I cannot boot to windows; So now I really want to just back up my documents that were on windows 10, it’s too much data for my 16GB USB stick.

I’d like to back it up inside of a GUI so I don’t miss anything, I have a desktop but I don't think I can connect the drive to it.

I could try a Linux CD but WinRE (Windows Recovery) tells me that the drive is locked so I don’t know if it will be for Linux too. I’ve had problems with Linux too.

I have a huge internal hard disk drive that has Windows XP on it but I don’t know how to boot to it, it booted itself after windows setup restarted the PC. I had to remove the Windows 10 drive just to get the Windows XP installer to work in legacy mode instead of UEFI mode.

When and *if* I can back my data up I’ll either just keep trouble free Windows XP and wipe Windows 10 or use Windows 7 instead of Windows 10 and Windows XP.

Any ideas? As I need to urgently get to my documents off of that drive.

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question; connect it to another machine, or boot into a live environment.

Comment: I made myself a little tool with which I recover files. You can try that ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/287439-emergency-kit-save-your-files-dead-os.html If you watch the videos, you should have no problem operating it. What makes you think the MBR is corrupted.

Comment: I get an error saying that bootmgr does not contain valid information for an operating system.

Comment: Michael Frank, I want the best solution, I don't want to be messing around more than needed

Comment: @snipe The best solution is the one that works. Without trying, how can you find out what works or not?

Comment: I've tried linux before, and I don't know how to connect it to another machine so maybe there not so good options

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu CDs boot into a live mode with a GUI. I've had excellent luck recovering files from drives where Windows refuses to boot anymore using that method. Good luck!!

**If your laptop supports multiple drives:** I've actually plugged a drive in while a system was online without issue. Once XP is up, plug in the drive. I honestly doubt anything bad would happen, and imagine that the worse that that could happen is that it doesn't recognize the drive. This will not work if your other drive has to be removed first.

You'll have to go into computer management to check that it showed up after connecting it. If it did, give it a drive letter, and see if you can access it.

Comment: I'm in XP now so, I'll wait for my battery to charge up fully, then give it a try, thanks!, the drive uses UEFI though so wont XP fail to recognize it?

Comment: wait, you have a laptop! You can't take the XP drive out to plug in the other drive and expect that to work. Sorry! I'll edit my answer, that won't work at all.

Comment: The XP drive does not need to come out. The windows 10 drive might need to, to back the data up off it.

Comment: Okay, that's fine then. Go for it!

Comment: so I'm unplugging the SSD containing Windows 10,  booting to XP,Then while XP is running, opening the laptop back up and plugging the SSD back in?

Answer (score 0):

Changing UEFI settings in the BIOS of your computer is often required to boot off of an external medium. It's often seen as UEFI or Secure boot in BIOS and you want it disabled. http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2417361,00.asp

The Hiberfil.sys file often prevents Ubuntu/linux from accessing/mounting a drive. You probably need to delete it. This is the file that stores the information when the computer goes into hibernation or doesn't shut down properly. http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/

Also, some bootable mediums (mentioned below) won't detect an internal harddrive unless harddrive mode from AHCI to IDE/RAID. These settings are also in the BIOS and need to be changed back when your all done.

Anyways, as for recovering data using a GUI. You can use the Ubuntu and the above tutorial to get access that way using the native Ubuntu File Manager. Otherwise you can adjust the aforementioned BIOS settings in order to boot to Hiren's Boot CD (has a live Mini XP version), UltimateBootCD, etc... and use one of the many tools to backup any/all data by several different means.